# how can i check session and redirect in android?

Tags: android

In  my application, a user can post comments only after logging in. So when a user clicks on comment activity, he/she will be redirected to login page and after successful login, he/she should redirect to that activity.

In this situation, I used `startactivityfor result()`, but it shows the page loading again. So when I click back button (using `finish()`), it again shows the same page.

I want to load the page only once.

Does anybody knows how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use sharedpreferences to save the state of users login, When the user enters ur loginscreen, if he is already logged in before, set flag as true and direct him to main page else false and ask him to log in again

Comment: My problem is after successful login,he /she redirects to the main page.But when i press the back button,it again shows the same page..I want to avoid that.

Comment: that means the page is loaded two times .

Comment: override on BackPressed....put some print statements and see what the log says. maybe you are not finishing the activity before going to next. Always use finish() in intents and then go to next activity. Then on back press, the previous activity wont be saved in stack

Comment: but when i finish() after startactivityonresult() in main page,it doesnt shows the main page after login.

Answer (score 0):

You can use use dialogue box for login for your comment activity. Let the user be on the same page, enable the user to login through the dialogue box and if the user enters the correct credentials let the user post the comment else show a toast instead.